# List supported SSL/TLS versions for a specific OpenSSL build

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl

I have, for example, OpenSSL version `1.0.0o` on my Linux system, and I want to know which `SSL/TLS` versions are supported with this build.

Is there a shell command to accomplish this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can not check for version support via command line. Best option would be checking [OpenSSL changelog](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html).

Openssl versions till 1.0.0h supports SSLv2, SSLv3 and TLSv1.0. From Openssl 1.0.1 onward support for TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 is added.

Comment: 1.0.1s and 1.0.2g up (March 2016) 'disable' SSLv2 (omit from builds) by default but `./Configure` can add it back. 1.1.0 base up (Aug. 2016) drops the code for SSLv2 entirely (can't add back) and disables SSLv3 by default.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, I am looking for a reference (release notes or elsewhere) that mentions the above stated by you regarding SSLv3. Would you please be able to provide one ?

Comment: @MohammedRaqeeb: I don't see it in the changelog, but it wasn't surprising, as 2016-08 was two years after POODLE and in addition to probably a hundred Qs on Stack, every security-related website in the world had been blaring "DON'T USE SSLv3!!! DON'T USE SSLv3!!!" incessantly.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeah, I agree. I had a Customer to whom I need to share this data hence was looking for a clear reference to the deprecating version.

Answer (score 174):

Use this

```
openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: **THIS IS WRONG.** The second column in `ciphers -v` is the _minimum_ version for the ciphersuite; since TLSv1.0 and 1.1 don't add any ciphersuites not present in SSLv3, in 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 this lists only `SSLv3` and `TLSv1.2` even though 1.0 and 1.1 are supported. In 1.1.0 due to an obvious bug 1.0 is listed, but 1.1 still is not. Also, 1.0.0-2 do support SSLv2 but don't put v2 suites in the _default_ cipherstring, so it isn't listed; that could be fixed by using `ALL`. (OTOH both SSLv3 and SSLv3 are broken and should not be _used_.)

Comment: PS: `sort|uniq` can be replaced by `sort -u` and awk can suppress duplicates by itself easily if the order doesn't matter or you use GNU awk 4 which has auto-sorting in `for`. But those are topics for SO.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

```
openssl s_client -help 2>&1  > /dev/null | egrep "\-(ssl|tls)[^a-z]"
```

Please let me know if this is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

It's clumsy, but you can get this from the usage messages for `s_client` or `s_server`, which are `#if`ed at compile time to match the supported protocol versions. Use something like

```
 openssl s_client -help 2>&1 | awk '/-ssl[0-9]|-tls[0-9]/{print $1}' 
 # in older releases any unknown -option will work; in 1.1.0 must be exactly -help
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following command:

```
openssl ciphers
```

This should produce a list of all of the ciphers supported in your version of openssl.

To see just a particular set of ciphers (e.g. just sslv3 ciphers) try:

```
openssl ciphers -ssl3
```

See https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html for more info.

Comment: I am not talking about ciphers.. i want to get supported SSL/TLS versions for specific OpenSSL build. For example: for 1.0.0o, SSL3 and TLS1 is supported.

Answer (score -2):

When you run OPENSSL command using s_client this is the output. See the Cipher, if the cipher NULL it means that version of TLS is not supported.

```
TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256
    Session-ID: A84600002D4945DE6
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:  
    Start Time: 15852343333860
    Timeout   : 2343 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Comment: This answers a different question.

Comment: Yes, you will need a local web server to perform the test, which may be configured to use not all ciphers. So the result may be incorrect.