# Python requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests

I would retrieve some information from an ABB G13 gateway that offer a RESTful JSON API. API is hosted by the gateway via https endpoint.
Basic authentication mechanism is used for authentication. However all traffic
goes through SSL layers.

On linux with command:

```
curl -s -k -X GET -u user:password https://host/meters/a_serial/power
```

All goes well!

I'm trying to write a script for windows in Python 2.7.10 with Requests 2.8.1 and with this code:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://host/meters/a_serial/power', auth=('user', 'password'))
```

I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mzilio/PycharmProjects/pwrgtw/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    requests.get('https://host/meters/a_serial/power', auth=('user', 'password'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 433, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

I've searched for a solution and I've tried to fix with this code:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl

class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
s.get('https://host/meters/a_serial/power')
```

But it doesn't work for me cause I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mzilio/PycharmProjects/pwrgtw/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    s.get('https://host/meters/a_serial/power')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 433, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

I'm stuck on this problem. Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Refer the stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/18579484#18579484

Comment: With the fix refered, a new error: `requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)`

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I am getting the same with an unrelated issue

Comment: Can't this randomly occur if internet connection shuts down in the middle of the script ?

Comment: Haunted me for a week, very sporadic. I had all the most up to date software and ssl stack.
Problem was I had two conflicting DNS entries for the same domain, one without an A record. Deleted that one and had to wait TTL 48h.

Answer (score 20):

This thing worked for me, just make sure whether these modules are installed or not, if not then install them, following are:

```
pip install ndg-httpsclient

pip install pyopenssl

pip install pyasn1
```

It removed my SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590) error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This did nothing for me.

Comment: I downvoted because it did nothing for me. I guess these libraries download stats went up for no reason o.o

Comment: I get this error trying to run pip!

Comment: It didn't help any how, explain how to use these modules after installing, will it automatic remove aur the request have to send through these modules.

Comment: ndg-httpsclient solved the issue for me while trying to run "pip install -r requirements.txt". Thank you enigma

Answer (score 17):

I found it was going through a proxy when it should have connected to the server directly.

I fixed this by doing

```
unset https_proxy
```

Comment: Where did you add this?

Comment: just in my linux terminal - it will unset the https_proxy environment variable.

Comment: saved the day. I was on a shared system.

Answer (score 17):

### Step 1: Check that Python supports TLS 1.1

You may have a Python setup that only supports TLS 1.0 – not TLS 1.1 or above.

You can check it like this:

**Python 3**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read()
```

**Python 2**

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read()
```

(If you get `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)>` you may have to disable certificate verification. ***NOTE: doing this will disable SSL protections against evildoers who would impersonate or intercept traffic to that website - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack***
)

```
import ssl
urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check', context=ssl._create_unverified_context()).read()
```

Check the output for the key `tls_version`. If it says `TLS 1.0` and not `TLS 1.1` or `TLS 1.2` that could be the problem.

If you're using a virtualenv, be sure to run the command inside.

### Step 2: Install Python with a newer version of OpenSSL

In order support TLS 1.1 or above, you may need to install a newer version of OpenSSL, and the install Python again afterwards. This should give you a Python that supports TLS 1.1.

The process depends on your operating system – here's a guide for [OS X](https://comeroutewithme.com/2016/03/13/python-osx-openssl-issue/).

**virtualenv users**
For me, the Python outside of my virtualenv had TLS 1.2 support, so just I removed my old virtualenv, and created a new one with the same packages and then it worked. Easy peasy!

Comment: Tried above and urlopen showed tls_version as 1.2 but still I get the same error : ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:579).

Any other ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: @Rama In that case you might be having a different issue. Like the missing `ndg-httpsclient` package as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467942/118608. I only know that the above answer (my answer) worked for me

Comment: one-line check from the command line:

`python -c "from urllib.request import urlopen ; print(urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read())"`

Comment: what version of openssl is required?

Comment: @HarryMoreno Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27545567/118608). TLS 1.1 is supported in Openssl 1.0.1 or later.

Comment: What could be the cause of the above code giving me `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>` ? I pass the exact string given above to `urlopen()`, and the error is the same for every well-formed URL.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same error, turns out that I didn't have `ndg-httpsclient` installed, see my original [issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3605) raised in github.

Comment: this way helps me

Comment: link deleted :/

Comment: Here's the updated link: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3605

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting this error for intermediate requests, you can refer to the solution mentioned in https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3391.

Basically, if you are making a lot of requests to a server and facing this issue with some of those requests you can use `Session` to just retry the requests.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: My service is doing 100+ requests to same server (different parameters) but after 70-80 request was getting this error. Changed the implementation to use Session and so far no error.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I have seen errors of this nature have been times that I was using `requests` to screen scrape data and I was using a multiprocessing library. I would either try your code without the pool manager or split your app into two apps, one that doles out urls and another that consumes them.

The client-server pair [here](https://github.com/hughdbrown/capstone/tree/master/rest) should give you some ideas. I was able to scale my client out horizontally when I used the hacky server code to load all urls into a Queue in memory just before `app.run`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Close you proxy and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

ENV: Python `3.10`, `www.howsmyssl.com` returns `tls_version: TLS 1.3`:

For poor guys like me who MUST make query through proxy, this cloud be blame on your incorrect **HTTPS proxy setting** (perhaps you aren't set it, but python somehow believes you've set it, don't know why exactly, maybe because you've set the http proxy), you need to set it "properly".

I'm using windows10, haven't set it before, after [set it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41570055/11397457), python works normally, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

try to run:
pip install urllib3==1.25.11

It works for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem when I was uploading large files. (The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 262144000 bytes.)
In order to debug this you should enable logging in your python script:

```
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, 
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

To tackle this I used:

```
#upload file to sharepoint
    local_path = 'out.csv'  # Local file path
    siteurl = sharepoint_baseurl + sharepoint_basesite
    test_user_credentials = UserCredential(sharepoint_username, sharepoint_password)
    ctx = ClientContext(siteurl).with_credentials(test_user_credentials)

    target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(sharepoint_upload_directory)
    size_chunk = 1000000
    with open(local_path, "rb") as f:
        uploaded_file = target_folder.files.create_upload_session(
            local_path, size_chunk, print
        ).execute_query()

    print("File {0} has been uploaded successfully".format(uploaded_file.serverRelativeUrl))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem when trying to do requests to YouTube API with python-youtube in a virtualenv. This worked for me:

```
from pyyoutube import Api

yt_api = Api(api_key="abc")
yt_api.session.verify = False
```