# Python: SSLError, bad handshake, Unexpected EOF

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an issue with connecting to a specific site using Python requests and get this error:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='XXXXXXXXX', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",),))

How can I work around this? (setting verify=False does not make a difference) I'm suspecting the server who's at fault here as it get an overall rating of F @ ssllabs when I run their test

I am fairly new with Python and requests

my code:

```
import requests
try:
    site = requests.get('https://XXXXXXXXXX', verify=True)
    print(site)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```

Comment: checkout this post: https://lukasa.co.uk/2017/02/Configuring_TLS_With_Requests/

Comment: I tried out the sample code from that blog post and it returns the same error
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)

Answer (score 2):

Faced with the same error my troubles went away after doing `pip install ndg-httpsclient`. `yum install python-ndg_httpsclient` or `apt-get install python-ndg-httpsclient` (or `apt-get install python3-ndg-httpsclient`) probably works too.

Comment: It does not seem to be available anymore. I got an error saying " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-ndg_httpsclient (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-ndg_httpsclient"

Comment: @DakshShah ...via pip?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/36499718/1657819 this error may happen if you're under proxy, so disabling proxy may help

```
unset https_proxy
```

Comment: I meet this case too, but I need a proxy to visit my aimed urls. Any suggestion for this situation?

Comment: @TranferWill I face the same issue as you.any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause might be [this open bug](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3829) in the *requests* library: "Session.verify=False ignored when REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable is set".

We've seen similar issues start all of a sudden on a specific host. It turned out that the env variable was set there recently, which started causing requests to spawn with session.verify not False despite being initialized to False. Once we removed the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable the errors stopped.

Comment: The OP questions doesn't yield the same error message :/

Comment: @MathieuK. fair point, in our case the error _was_ as OP's (and not as in the linked _requests_ bug). Removing the environment var resolved the issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

Set `verify = False`, it will help:

```
import requests
try:
    site = requests.get('https://XXXXXXXXXX', verify=False)
    print(site)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```

or try with `urllib`:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

try:
    site =urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
    print(site.read().decode())
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```