# Getting Dialogflow : API Core Service Unavaible Error

Tags: exception, dialogflow-es

> google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata
>   from plugin failed with error:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad
>   handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')")))

Tried multiple solutions available on internet like updating the pyOpenSSL version and other below solutions

[Python: SSLError, bad handshake, Unexpected EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142848/python-sslerror-bad-handshake-unexpected-eof)

https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4246

Comment: This happens because your machine is blocking some urls that oauth2.googleapis.com calls while doing intent detection on dialogflow

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your machine is blocking some urls that oauth2.googleapis.com calls while doing intent detection on dialogflow