# Python Script requests.get() runs on one computer but not the other

Tags: python, python-requests

I have pretty basic script to get a JSON response from my server, on one Mac it works, on the other I get the following error.

```
  File "script.py", line 10, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url = URL)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)
```

Here is the code.

```
start = "2020-01-01"
end = "2020-03-01"
URL = "https://www.url.app/api/v1/item.php?start=%s&end=%s" % (start, end)
r = requests.get(url = URL)
print(r.tojson())
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Both computers have Python 2.7

Comment: Are both your computers in the same network?

Comment: yes, they are on the same network. @TimWoocker

Comment: have you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410577/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol on the second computer?

Comment: yes @Sadap I found this also and tried it. didnt work for me.

Comment: Are both Python installations/environments the same?

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked

```
pip install requests[security]
```

I found this answer here:
https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3605#issuecomment-256425497