# Connecting to a Postgres Database over SSL using Sockets in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sockets, ssl, openssl

I am trying to connect to a Postgres Database using sockets to enforce a particular TLS version from the client in order to verify that the Database does not accept connections from the client which uses an older version of TLS like tlsv1.1. The connection is failing on handshake with the following error :

python test2.py

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test2.py", line 12, in
>
> ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)   File "<>/python3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1232, in
> get_server_certificate
> with context.wrap_socket(sock) as sslsock:   File "<>/python3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
> _context=self, _session=session)   File "<>/python3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in **init**
> self.do_handshake()   File "<>/python3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()   File "<>/python3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:852)

The following is a snippet of the code:

```
    import socket
    import ssl
    
    hostname = <DB_Endpoint>
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    
    with socket.create_connection((hostname, 8200)) as sock:
        with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
            print(ssock.version())
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See for some solutions mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410577/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol