# Cannot install any package with pip 21.0.1 SSLEOFError

Tags: python, pip

I'm using python 3.7 with pip 21.0.1 on Ubuntu1604. I can't install any python package with the error

```
yc_qian@NiBaBa:~$ pip install pyopenssl
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pyopenssl/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pyopenssl/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pyopenssl/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pyopenssl/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pyopenssl/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/pyopenssl/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyopenssl/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyopenssl
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyopenssl
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
```

I found the similar issue on [github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9568) but had no idea how to fix it. I also tried to downgrade pip, but the command also use pip, so it bumped into the same error...

How can I solve this?

Comment: I've receive a similar error when running Fiddler on my machine. If you are running it try turning it of.

Comment: @FelixEklöf No fiddler, I did run a VPN, but it made no difference if I turn it off and try install again..

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467942/7088596

Answer (score 3):

According to the answer that Felix mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410577/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol), I solved the problem by

```
unset http_proxy https_proxy
```