# What could be causing "SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol" when using requests.get() to access YouTube videos in python?

Tags: python, error-handling, python-requests, http-status-codes

I am very new to programming and the computer world in general. I am trying to send a request to [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) using the requests module. When I type its address in my browser, everything works just fine and I can access YouTube without any problems. However, when I try to access YouTube with the following Python code:

```
import requests
requests.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

I encounter the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 700, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 996, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 369, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 504, in _connect_tls_proxy
    socket = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.youtube.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\BeBit\Desktop\Python WorkPlace\MyProjectsandOnlyMines\YouTubeDownload.py", line 7, in <module>
    requests.get("https://www.youtube.com")
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BeBit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.youtube.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol 
(_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

I'm using a vless configuration in v2rayN if this information can help.
can someone tell me what should I do?

"I expected to get <Response [200]> but I encountered a lot of errors."

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410577/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol