# SSL Error Message when posting to Wordpress with RWordpress

Tags: r, wordpress, knitr

I  try to post to my Wordpress site using the RWordpress package (https://github.com/duncantl/RWordPress). This worked until recently, and I now get the following error message.

```
options(WordPressLogin = c(bla = 'fasel'),
        WordPressURL = 'https://www.econinfo.de/xmlrpc.php')

getRecentPostTitles()

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Searching around, it seems that there is a conflict with the TLS version, but I don't understand on what side. The certificate from my hoster supports TSL 1.1 and TLS 1.2.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm on Win 10 with

```
> RCurl::curlVersion()
$age
[1] 3

$version
[1] "7.40.0"

$vesion_num
[1] 468992

$host
[1] "x86_64-pc-win32"

$features
      ssl      libz      ntlm asynchdns    spnego largefile       idn      sspi 
        4         8        16       128       256       512      1024      2048 

$ssl_version
[1] "OpenSSL/1.0.0o"
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when using `RCurl::postForm("https://www.econinfo.de/xmlrpc.php")`?

Comment: Yes, same error.

Comment: What OS are you using? Which version of libcurl do you have installed? The above command works fine on Debian testing with libcurl version 7.65.3.

Comment: See edit about version and OS

Comment: The version of OpenSSL is to old, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27545567/8416610. I guess CRAN would have to update their very old libcurl/openssl versions to get updated binaries.

Comment: I'm trying to build the package from source now, but now I am in dependencies hell. /x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl

Comment: You can get a recent libcurl build using the R-on-Windows toolchain from https://github.com/rwinlib/libcurl. However, I am not sure if that can be used with RCurl.

Answer (score 7):

The RWordpress package [has not been touched for over 7 years](https://github.com/duncantl/RWordPress). You might want to explore other options.

These days, people use the `curl` or `httr` package for internet access. The `RCurl` package has been unmaintained for years unfortunately, and it only supports very old version of SSL (apparenlty not  TSL 1.1 and TLS 1.2)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Windows 10 you can eventually download [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) and easily manage and disable TLS and SSL.

But @Jeron is right, RWordpress is deprecated.