# Can't see output in wordpress when using knit2wp

Tags: html, wordpress, r-markdown

I successfully published to wordpress using knit2wp. My only problem is that in my R code I do one plot that won't show up in wordpress.

The plot appears when I knit locally both to pdf or html... but not in wordpres. I have checked the parameters that I can pass to knit2wp none of them relate to 'showing plots'. What am I missing?

Comment: I am also struggling with this. Found a post that suggested setting the `opts_knit$set(upload.fun = function(file){uploadFile(file)$url})`  parameter but I still cant get it to work. Source:  https://datascienceplus.com/posting-from-r-markdown-to-datascienceplus/. Anyone else??

Answer (score 1):

Managed a work around which is not ideal but at least shows something.

Here's an example plot:

```
plt <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = cyl)) + geom_point()
```

Then save the plot to the working directory:

```
   ggsave("newplot.png")
```

Use the `RWordPress` `uploadFile` function to upload the saved png to your WordPress media library:

```
uploadFile("newplot.png", "image/png")
```

Insert the following html code in the body of your Rmd file to reference the image file when the post renders in WordPress.

```
<img src="https://YOURSITE.files.wordpress.com/YEAR/MONTH/newplot.png" alt="newplot"/>
```

In the above example you would need to replace `YEAR` and `MONTH` with the corresponding values for the period in which you upload your image files. For example if you uploaded your file in March 2020 then replace `YEAR` with `2020` and `MONTH` with `03`.

From there you can run the `knit2wp` function.

Comment: Hi when I try to use the uploadFile function (uploadFile("newplot.png", "image/png"))..... I get the following message: 

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version.......any idea what that means?

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478582/ssl-error-message-when-posting-to-wordpress-with-rwordpress